# Convert CURL "-i --user" to C# HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, curl, httpwebrequest, plivo

I want to run a CURL POST to send SMS message via Plivo API service.

I do it by using HttpWebRequest in C# (see below).

Parametres as as follow:
POSTurl = "https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/MA****************M2/Message/'”
JSONRequest == "src=+972545675453&dst=0545675453&text=TEST”

In their docs I need to user the following parameter:
 -i --user AUTH_ID:AUTH_TOKEN

I don't know how to implement this but it not work (401 error -unauthorised)
I tried to use it instead auth parameter in my code as follow:
auth ==  “MA****************MM2:Yj**************************M5ZjA4"

Need some advice

Thanks

This is my code:

```
public static SqlString POSTSG(String POSTurl, String auth, SqlString JSONRequest)
{
    SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;



    //Create Request
    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(POSTurl);
    myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";


    myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
    myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    streamWriter.Write(JSONRequest);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();

    // Get the response
    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    // Create a new read stream for the response body and read it
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
    SqlString result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();


    return (result);





}
```

Comment: Best method is to send message without application and then trace messages using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  You will learn a lot.  Then modify your code to send same as without your application.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to send User:Pass as network credentials instead of auth. and use 'application/json' as content type.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static SqlString POST(String POSTurl, String auth,String user, String pass, String ContentType, SqlString JSONRequest)
{
    SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;



    //Create Request
    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(POSTurl);
    myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    if (user != null)   { myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass); }
    else if (auth!=null) { myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth); }
    myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = ContentType;
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
    streamWriter.Write(JSONRequest);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();

    // Get the response
    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    // Create a new read stream for the response body and read it
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    SqlString result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();



    return (result);

}
```